# The "VsInstallRoot" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore" task

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I've got a Xamarin.Forms app and when I try to build the Android app I get the following compile time error:

```
Target _XamarinAndroidBuildAarRestore:

/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.9/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(120,4): 
error MSB4064: The "VsInstallRoot" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.9/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): 
error MSB4063: The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
```

The iOS app builds fine.

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac (version 7.4.1 build 48).

Comment: Do you have firebase or google maps in your application?

Comment: Hey, I am going to try to reproduce the issue here on my end. We just released the 0.4.9 update, but I've not heard of this issue. Are you able to share what version of Google Play Services you are using?

Comment: @G.hakim I do have google maps in my application.

Comment: @clb This was also happening using version 0.4.7 of Xamarin.Build.Download. I'm using version 42.1021.1 of Google Play Services.

Comment: That is quite a gap between Google Play Services and Xamarin.Build.Download. Are you able to either update GPS to latest, or, and this is probably a bit easier, downgrade Xamarin.Build.Download to 0.4.6. I am working on getting this bug to occur on my end right now.

Comment: @cobey I tried downgrading Xamarin.Build.Download to 0.4.6 and got the same error. When I upgrade Xamarin.Build.Download and Google Play Services to the latest I get a similar, but slightly different error:

error MSB4064: The "User7ZipPath" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this error to go away by deleting the packages, bin, and obj folders from my solution as referenced in this Xamarin Forum:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96703/the-user7zippath-parameter-is-not-supported